# Excel VBA for reporting

Tags: excel, vba

Can anyone help me out with the VBA code the following problem:

[image]

In the above picture, different names are mentioned and I need to prepare a report with 
Villa no, customer name and column name which has the value of "client delay"

Comment: Is there any reason that you need to use VBA for this? It looks like it could be done with formulas only.

Comment: @jsheeran am I missing something obvious?  Seems to me it *could* be done with a very complex set of worksheet formulas. I assume there are variable number of columns filled in, not all are populated, and possibly more than one column per more (however that's assumptions)

Comment: @rah  - Could there be more than one "client delay" per row row?  ...per column?   will there always be at least one per column, but not necessarily one per row?

Comment: I think `=INDEX($C$1:$E$1,1,MATCH("client delay",$C2:$E2,0))` in column F would do the trick. Just trap the errors to your needs for those without "client delay".

Comment: I appreciate your help, I'm already using the same formula. But I need to work on a more complex scenario, this is just an example of it. So, VBA will be of good help to me